# Problems binding events to dynamically created elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, bind, jquery-click-event

```
$.each(data, function(i,data) {
...[cut]...
    +"<a id=\"contact_"+data.id+"_delete\" href=\"/user/contact/delete/ticket_id/"+data.ticket_id+"/contact_id/"+data.id+"\">Delete</a>"
...[cut]...
    $("#contact_"+data.id+"_delete").live('click',function() {
        var href = this.attr('href');
        alert(href);
        return false;
    });
```

I have the following code sample (irrelevant parts cut out for simplicity).  What I have is a function that redraws the rows (tr's) of a table.  Each row has a 'delete' link at the end of the row that calls a url /user/contact/delete/ticket_id/{$ticket_id}

Then (within the same loop), I want to bind a click event to the newly created link.  However when I click the link, the browser leaves the page and goes to the url rather than going to the clicked link function.

First, am I binding the click event properly?

Second, am I retrieving the 'href' attribute of the element correctly?

Comment: at the moment: 1.3.0 (google cdn)

Comment: fyi, I changed it to 1.7.1 and am still getting the same results

Comment: i would change to use `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: I changed live with on, and it is the same result, however *now* it is showing the alert properly, *but* it is still redirecting to the page rather than staying on the current page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what `@charlietfl` says, you could have a single handler for all of your delete elements.  Simply add the same class to all of them, like `class="contact_delete"`, and then use `.on()` to target all of them:

```
+'<a class="contact_delete" id="contact_'+data.id+'_delete" ...
```

Note that if you use single quotes, you don't have to escape all of your double-quotes.

```
$('body').on('click', '.contact_delete', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(href);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok that took care of it, sometimes I think to linear when I am working with pieces, but working with elements.  I forget to step back and look at the big picture once in a while.  I am not sure why it was following through to the 'link' page when I was returning false, but by moving things around and attaching the event to the body like that, worked great, thanks to you and @charlietfl

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap "this" in $() to make it a jQuery object in order to use jQuery methods

```
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

live() is deprecated ( but working in 1.7.1) so you should consider using more current on() method